# Can't Find My Token on Metamask

Tags: myetherwallet, metamask, etherscan, wallet-transfer

I bought PAY tokens on etherdelta.github.io .  They show on Etherscan under the "Token Transfers" tab, but they do not show on Metamask. Metamask reports "No Tokens Found" on its Tokens tab.  I would like to send the tokens to my Myetherwallet, but am not able to do so because Metamask doesn't show I have tokens.

What am I misunderstanding?  Doing wrong?  How do I transfer tokens from Etherscan using Metamask??

Thanks in advance for your help!!!

Comment: I am having the same issue. I successfully bought and transferred a token from Etherdelta to my MetaMask account. A few days later I needed to change the password. When I did, and used the seed phrase during the process, the MetaMask account reloaded without the tokens. First thought was to re-add the address and symbol, but that nothing. How can I find my tokens on etherscan? or on Meta mask? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I am sure you would have resolved it by now, but I am just putting an answer here for someone who lands here seeking a solution to this question.

Well, to see any new ERC20 tokens under the TOKENS tab on MetaMask wallet, first you have to add the specifics of that token manually.

[This post](https://steemit.com/eos/@tech-nomad/can-t-find-the-eos-tokens-on-my-metamask-wallet) explains it here for EOS tokens. You need to do the same for TenX or PAY or any other token with their particular specifics.

Let me put down the PAY tokens specific that you will need to fill. You can easily find them on their official site.

Token Address: 0xB97048628DB6B661D4C2aA833e95Dbe1A905B280
Token Symbol: PAY 
Decimals of Precision: 18

Hope it helps you.